# Azure DataWarehouse load CSV with external Table

Tags: azure-blob-storage, sql-data-warehouse

I can't find a complete example on how I would be able to load a CSV file directlry with a external table into a Sql Datawarehouse.
The file is on a Storage account https://tstodummy.blob.core.windows.net/
Blob container referencedata-in, folder csv-uploads, file something.csv.
This is my code

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL tstodummy_refdata_credential
  WITH IDENTITY = 'USER',
  SECRET = '....'
GO

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE tstodummy_referencedata
  WITH ( TYPE = HADOOP,
         LOCATION = 'wasb://referencedata-in@tstodummy.blob.core.windows.net',
         CREDENTIAL = tstodummy_refdata_credential);
GO

CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT aps_bma_referencedata_ff
WITH (FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,
      FORMAT_OPTIONS(
          FIELD_TERMINATOR = ';',
          STRING_DELIMITER = '"',
          FIRST_ROW = 2, 
          USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = True)
)

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [stg_aps_bma_refdata].[PlanDeMaintenance]
  ( [Version]     VARCHAR(255) NULL
  , [Description] VARCHAR(255) NULL
  , [Date_Start]  VARCHAR(255) NULL
  , [Date_Stop]   VARCHAR(255) NULL
  ) WITH ( LOCATION = '\referencedata-in\csv-uploads\PlanDeMaintanance'
         , DATA_SOURCE = tstodummy_referencedata
         , FILE_FORMAT = aps_bma_referencedata_ff
         , REJECT_TYPE = VALUE
         , REJECT_VALUE = 0
         )
```

I've been playing with all kind of combinations in the Location ... But, Nogo
The error is

```
Msg 105002, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
EXTERNAL TABLE access failed because the specified path name '/referencedata-in/csv-uploads/PlanDeMaintanance.csv' does not exist. Enter a valid path and try again.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this did the trick in case of others encounterig the sale troubles.
I did not yet add, in this code the remark I received, meanwhile done.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE tsto_referencedata
  WITH ( TYPE = HADOOP,
         LOCATION = 'wasb://referencedata-in@tsto.blob.core.windows.net',
         CREDENTIAL = tsto_refdata_credential);
GO

CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT aps_bma_referencedata_ff
WITH (FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,
      FORMAT_OPTIONS(
          FIELD_TERMINATOR = ',',
          STRING_DELIMITER = '"',
          FIRST_ROW = 2, 
          USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = True)
)

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [stg_aps_bma_refdata].[PlanDeMaintenance.csv]
  ( [Version]     VARCHAR(255) NULL
  , [Description] VARCHAR(255) NULL
  , [Date_Start]  VARCHAR(255) NULL
  , [Date_Stop]   VARCHAR(255) NULL
  ) WITH ( LOCATION = '/csv-uploads/PlanDeMaintenance.csv'
         , DATA_SOURCE = tsto_referencedata
         , FILE_FORMAT = aps_bma_referencedata_ff
         , REJECT_TYPE = VALUE
         , REJECT_VALUE = 0
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your storage structure, but I think you'll find that the problem is the inclusion of "/referencedata-in" in the external table location.

One small thing, you might also want to consider a "wasbs" prefix on your storage URL, so that SSL encryption is applied to the transfer.